# How to convert HDC to WORD (unsigned short)

Tags: c++, casting

Is there a way to convert HDC (afxwin.h) to WORD (unsigned short)? I tried to use `static_cast` and C style cast but both it doesn't help.  Anyone have idea?

```
HDC x;
WORD y = static_cast<WORD>(x);
```

[invalid type conversion]

```
HDC x;
WORD y = (WORD)x;
```

[warning C4302: 'type cast': truncation from 'HDC' to 'WORD']

**Actual code line**

```
DefWindowProc(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, (WORD)dc.m_hDC, 0L);
```

Comment: What about `reinterpret_cast`? It is essentially equivalent to C-style cast, so take into consideration that if you get a compilation error for `static_cast`, then it might be for a good reason (probably data truncation). Oh... I actually see it now in the second half of your question. That `HDC` type is probably a 4-byte variable. If you feel safe with the truncation, then just go ahead with `reinterpret_cast` (or simply suppress that warning).

Comment: What is this cast going to accomplish?

Comment: @chirs: one function returns the HDC and second accept WORD as a argument. both are 3rd party. cannot change the signature.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya, Which function in particular are you passing it to, or is it not part of the winapi?

Comment: A HDC doesn't fit in a short, you lose at least half the bits depending on 32/64 bit.  Smells like an XY problem or trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: @chirs: added the actual code line

Comment: Ah, `WPARAM`, unlike its name indicates, is not a `WORD`. It used to be AFAIK, but not anymore. It's a [`UINT_PTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is a 32-bit or 64-bit unsigned integer such that it will fit a pointer. You should just be casting to `WPARAM` (preferably with `reinterpret_cast`).

Comment: @chris: I'm working with VS2015 preview. porting a project to new version.

Comment: That shouldn't matter.  Find the typedef in WinDef.h.  I'd be shocked if it wasn't `typedef UINT_PTR WPARAM;`.

Comment: FWIW, here's [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/25/55850.aspx) on the history of `WPARAM` and `LPARAM`.

Comment: Windows Data Types:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx

`typedef void *PVOID;` 
`typedef PVOID HANDLE;` 
`typedef HANDLE HDC;`
`typedef unsigned short WORD;`  So you will be throwing away a lot of bits.

Comment: @RichardCritten, Unfortunately (for that article, but quite the opposite in general), that's not always true for the handle types. If you [define `STRICT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383681(v=vs.85).aspx), they will each be a different type.

Comment: @chris i know, just trying to give an online reference.  With Strict defined they are still the same size, so what the OP is trying to do is not going to work. He has an X-Y problem.

Comment: So any workaround to overcome my issue?

Comment: You're casting to the wrong type.  Cast to `WPARAM` as @chris said earlier.  If that does not work, copy/paste the compile error into your question.